# Received the job offer that match to my salary expectation, should I make a counter offer/re-negotiate asking for more?

Tags: negotiation

I did the interview 3 days ago, and they offered me the salary that match my expectation in "Gross" and the "job offer" letter. Should I re-negotiate to get "Net" salary?

Comment: You gave them a salary you expected, and they gave it to you. Unless something extraordinary has happened in the past 3 days, which would justify them paying you a higher salary, I cannot see why you would ask for it. Can you explain why you think doing this might be justified?

Comment: No, you should not.  However, you *should* make a note, for any future interviews you might conduct, to give your "expected salary" in Gross.

Comment: Never ever have I heard anyone ask for a net salary. They have no way of knowing what different deductions etc you will have, so can't calculate the net until you fill out the personnel forms at a the start of your employment. They don't know what medical you will pick, if your tax deductions are for one person or for a family of 6, whether you will choose extra life insurance or dental insurance, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with re-negotiating your offer letter, if you have new arguments. If nothing has changed since your interview, then I wouldn't suggest it.

E.g. I had the same dilemma before. I got offered what I requested, but in the meantime I have received +20% offer from another company. I told the first company that I really want to work for them, but the salary gap between these two offers is too big and I would like them to increase the initial offer by 15%. They agreed.

All in all, if anything has changed since interview it's always worth to ask.